# How to avoid Jquery qtip appears multiple times for same target?

Tags: jquery, qtip

I've the following code which displays qtip making ajax call on click of svg node. However when I click the same element (target) multiple times, it loads no of qtips for the same target. What am I missing?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                        $('image').click(function() {
                            var $img = $(this);

                            $(this).qtip({
                                content: 'Loading...',
                                style: {
                                    border: {
                                        width: 5,
                                        radius: 10
                                    },
                                    padding: 10,
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    tip: true, // Give it a speech bubble tip with automatic corner detection
                                    name: 'cream' // Style it according to the preset 'cream' style
                                },
                                hide: { delay: 2000 },
                                show: {
                                    when: 'click', // Don't specify a show event
                                    ready: true, // Show the tooltip when ready
                                    solo: true
                                },
                                position: {
                                    corner: {
                                        tooltip: 'bottomRight', // Use the corner...
                                        target: 'bottomLeft' // ...and opposite corner
                                    }
                                },
                                api: {
                                    // Retrieve the content when tooltip is first rendered
                                    onRender: function() {
                                        var self = this;
                                        self.content = '';
                                        $.ajax({
                                            url: window.location.href,
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            data: 'call=ajax&uid=' + $img.attr('data-uid'),
                                            success: function(resp) {
                                                self.updateContent(resp);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    },
                                    onContentUpdate: function() {
                                        var self = this;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
```

Note : I am using jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The qtip initialization should be invoked once, and not on the click event. It's typically done when the document has been loaded.

The tip appears when you hoover an element.

**Update**

The show option should be configured as:

```
show: {
  when: {
      event: 'click'
  }
}
```

Complete initialization:

```
$(function() {
    $('image').qtip({
        content: 'Loading...',
        style: {
            border: {
                width: 5,
                radius: 10
            },
            padding: 10,
            textAlign: 'center',
            tip: true, // Give it a speech bubble tip with automatic corner detection
            name: 'cream' // Style it according to the preset 'cream' style
        },
        hide: { delay: 2000 },
        show: {
            when: {
                event: 'click'
            }, 
            ready: true, // Show the tooltip when ready
            solo: true
        },
        position: {
            corner: {
                tooltip: 'bottomRight', // Use the corner...
                target: 'bottomLeft' // ...and opposite corner
            }
        },
        api: {
            // Retrieve the content when tooltip is first rendered
            onRender: function() {
                var self = this;
                self.content = '';
                $.ajax({
                    url: window.location.href,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'call=ajax&uid=' + $img.attr('data-uid'),
                    success: function(resp) {
                        self.updateContent(resp);
                    }
                });
            },
            onContentUpdate: function() {
                var self = this;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But what if I want to display qtip for each svg node on click? How can I achieve that?

Comment: You do that with the `show` option. The tip plugin should still be initialized during document startup.

Comment: I've solved my problme with few lines of code. Thanks everyone who replied my thread.

    $(document).ready(function() {

          $('image').click(function() {
         
               var $img = $(this);

               if ($img.data('qtip')) { return false; }

               //rest of the code
          });
    });

Comment: You do the same as I said but in a more messy way.

Comment: As all the images in div loaded dynamically, it loads qtip as soon as it gets initialized. Check below modified code.

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myChart image').each(
   function() {
    var $img = $(this);

                // if ($img.data('qtip')) { return false; }

    $(this).qtip({ // rest code 
    });
   });
});